# lambert W function solution for $\ln x=a+bx^{-1}$

Tags: special-functions

Is is possible to solve the equation $\ln x=a+bx^{-1}$ using the Lambert W function? I understand that the lambert W function is the solution for equations like $\ln x=bx^{-1}$, which does not apply here.

Comment: According to CAS the solution is:  ${{\rm e}^{{\it LambertW} \left( {\frac {b}{{{\rm e}^{a}}}} \right) +a}
}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it seems so, $\ln x=a+bx^{-1}$ being equivalent to $$\ln (x/e^a) = (b/e^a)/(x/e^a). $$